# Hazelcast: Same entries appear in different partitions

Tags: hazelcast

I have been experimenting with Hazelcast PartitionPredicate and noticed a same key can appear in multiple partitions. Could someone please explain why this is ? or if you know a good article that explains this behaviour ?

Sample code:

Create test cache:

```
   def hzCreateTestCache(): Unit = {
        val hzClient: HazelcastInstance = getClient
        val testCache = hzClient.getMap[HzMapKey, HzMapValue]("Test")
        // delete all entries.
        testCache.destroy()
        for (i <- 1 to 100000) {
          var d = 20171224
          if (i > 50 * 1000) d = 20171225
          val key = new HzMapKey {_date = d; _Id = "id_" + f"$i%010d"}
          val value = new HzMapValue {_body = "body_" + key}
          testCache.put(key, value)
        }
      }
```

Read from cache:

```
  def test_read_all_entries_by_partition(): Unit = {
    val client = getClient
    val testsMap = client.getMap[HzMapKey, HzMapValue]("Test")
    println("Size: " + testsMap.size())
    val datePredicate = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject.get("__key#_date").equal(20171224)
    var c = 0
    var partValues = Array[String]()
    // foreach Hz partition
    client.getPartitionService.getPartitions.toArray().foreach(p => {
      // create partitionPredicate with PartitionId
      val partPredicate = new PartitionPredicate(p.asInstanceOf[Partition].getPartitionId, datePredicate)
      val values = testsMap.keySet(partPredicate)
      // Increment counter
      c = c + values.size()
      // Insert into partValues for later...
      values.toArray().foreach(i => partValues = partValues :+ i.asInstanceOf[HzMapKey].toString)
    })
    println("Count: " + partValues.length)
    // find duplicates
    partValues.groupBy(i => i.toString).map(t => (t._1, t._2.length)).foreach(e => if (e._2 > 1) println(e._1 + ": " + e._2))
  }
```

This returns:

Size: 100000
Count: 50295
...

Comment: The first argument to `PartitionPredicate` should be a key not the partition id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Neil but I am not sure what you mean by "key" here. 
My understanding is the the PartitionPredicate takes in the partition id and an inner predicate that will be applied on the partition specified only. http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/PartitionPredicate.html

Comment: It's a big more clearly explained here http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.1/manual/html-single/index.html#filtering-with-partition-predicate. The first argument to the partition predicate is an object (`HzMapKey`) from which Hazelcast derives single partition to run the predicate against. You're actually passing in an Integer. So if field one is int:1 the partition selected is 31. That might explain the odd results you get, or it might not. Certainly it clouds the analysis. Each unique key will be in one partition only, you just need to find a way to confirm it.